# Can somebody tell me why my function removes some vowels and not others?

Tags: python, replace

```
def withoutVowels(string):
    for letter in string:
        if letter in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
            noVowelString = string.replace(letter, " ")
            return noVowelString
```

This function removes and replaces a, e but not i, o, u and i am not sure why.

Comment: Please include actual input and actual and expected output when asking a question like this.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've done Python, but it appears your function returns after replacing the first vowel.

Maybe this is what you want:

```
def withoutVowels(string):
    noVowelString = ""
    for letter in string:
        if letter in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
            noVowelString += " "
        else:
            noVowelString += letter

     return noVowelString
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for letter in string:
    if letter in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
        noVowelString = string.replace(letter, " ")
        return noVowelString
```

Think about that. You have a for loop, and if a condition inside the loop body is evaluated as true, then you do something *and return from the function*. So all remaining loop iterations won’t ever run.

Instead, you would want to move the `return` out of the loop, so it can still continue. However, you also would want to keep the changed string you did your replacements on once, and continue on that one:

```
def withoutVowels(string):
    noVowelString = string
    for letter in string:
        if letter in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
            noVowelString = noVowelString.replace(letter, " ")
    return noVowelString
```

Finally, this all does not really make sense. There is no need to iterate over *every* character of your original string, if you just want to remove all vowels from the string. Instead, you can just loop over the vowels, and remove them:

```
def withoutVowels(string):
    for vowel in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"):
        string = string.replace(vowel, "")
    return string
```

Answer (score 1):

There are five things here:

1. Your return-statement is indented too far.  As soon as control enters the if-block for the first time, the for-loop will stop iterating and the function will return prematurely.
2. String objects are immutable in Python.  Hence, [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) returns a modified *copy* of the string instead of modifying the original object.  This means that you need to reassign `string` to the copy in each iteration of the for-loop.
3. Your for-loop should be iterating over the list of vowels, not the input string.  Or, even more efficient, a string of vowels.
4. Because your function is supposed to *remove* vowels from the string, I think it would be better to replace them with an empty string instead of a space.
5. Your function does not remove uppercase vowels.

Below is a version of your function that addresses these issues:

```
def withoutVowels(string): 
    for vowel in "aeiouAEIOU":
        string = string.replace(vowel, "")
    return string
```